# CSS even odd for every other odd div in class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have divs in a horizontal row, all in the same class, like this:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

What I want is to apply css to every other odd column, so
1,5,9, etc.

I've tried

```
.myClass:nth-child(n+4) and
.myClass:nth-child(odd),.myClass:nth-child(odd){
```

but can't figure it out :(

Comment: You can use `:nth-child(4n+1)`. See documentation for more details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:nth-child(4n)` gives us 0, 4, 8, etc.

Since you want 1, 5, 9, you should try [`:nth-child(4n + 1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is apply the css to every fourth row, so you want to do:

```
.myClass:nth-child(4n+1)
```