# Adding a css class to every other item when looping through ViewModel in a razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In a razor view I am trying to display quotes. When I loop through the list of quotes in the ViewModel I need to be able to add a class of blockquote-reverse to every other item in the list.

**Please see below:**

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel>

    @foreach (var customer in Model)
    {
         @* if index is odd *@ 
<blockquote>
  <p>@customer.Name</p>
  <footer>@customer.Quote</cite></footer>
</blockquote>

@* if index is even *@ 
<blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">
  <p>@customer.Name</p>
  <footer>@customer.Quote</cite></footer>
</blockquote>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a variable for tracking the index of a record, and use mod operator (`%`) to choose correct CSS class:

```
@{int i = 0;}
@foreach (var customer in Model)
{
    var className = i % 2 == 0 ? "blockquote-reverse" : null;
    i++;
    <blockquote class="@className">
       <p>@customer.Name</p>
       <footer><cite>@customer.Quote</cite></footer>
    </blockquote>
}
```

**NOTE**: You have a closing tag `</cite>` without an opening tag in your code, I added opening tag to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.. I keep forgetting I can pretty much do anything in razor that I can do in c#...

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable for an indexer so you can use the `%` operator

```
@{ var index = 0; }
@foreach (var customer in Model)
{
    if (index % 2 == 0)
    {
        .... // without class name
    }
    else
    {
        .... // with class name
    }
    index++;
}
```

Side note: You can also consider using css to style the elements using a `:nth-child(2n)` selector (for an example, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232650/css-even-odd-for-every-other-odd-div-in-class))